# How to make parent component listen to changes made by child component efficiently in Angular 2?

Tags: angular, menu, components, angular2-routing, logout

This is mainly a design/approach issue.

**What I wanted to achieve :**
=> Hide the logout link when the user is logged out. Make the logout link visible only when the user is logged in.

**Problem :**
Menu and logout are two different components. So, when an user clicks logout, to pass this information to menu component proved to be very difficult. I am looking for a more proper/straightforward approach. Please give me suggestions.
My code snippets are given below -

menu.component.html

```
<div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li routerLinkActive="active"> <a [routerLink]="[ '/home' ]" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a></li>
    <li routerLinkActive="active" *ngIf="loggedIn">
      <app-logout (onLogOutClick)="onLogOutClick($event)"></app-logout>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

menu.component.ts

```
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-menu',
  templateUrl: './menu.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./menu.component.css'],
  providers: [SharedService]
})
export class MenuComponent implements OnInit {

  loggedIn: boolean = false;
  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loggedIn = this.sharedService.isLoggedIn();
  }

  onLogOutClick($event) {
    this.loggedIn = false;
  }
}
```

logout.component.html

```
<a [routerLink]="[ '/logout' ]" routerLinkActive="active" (click)="onClick()">Logout</a>
```

logout.component.ts

```
   import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Component, EventEmitter, OnInit, Output, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { SharedService } from '../shared.service';
import { ModalComponent } from '../modal.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-logout',
  templateUrl: './logout.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logout.component.css'],
  providers: [SharedService]
})
export class LogoutComponent implements OnInit {

  @Output() onLogOutClick = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(private sharedService: SharedService, private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onClick() {
    console.log('logout component : onclick clicked..');

    if (this.sharedService.isLoggedIn) {
      this.sharedService.logout();
      this.onLogOutClick.emit(true);

    } else {
      // shouldn't reach
      console.log('User not logged in. Discarding logout attempt');
    }
    this.routeToLoginPage();

  }

  routeToLoginPage() {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

}
```

Comment: state management techniques.

Answer (score 0):

In your `SharedService` define an `Observable` that you can access to determine whether the user is logged in or not.

```
@Injectable()
export class SharedService {

    isLoggedIn$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false)

    login(): void {
        // login business logic
        this.isLoggedIn$.next(true)
    }

    logout(): void {
        // logout business logic
        this.isLoggedIn$.next(false)
    }
}
```

Have any component subscribe to the `isLoggedIn$` state. E.g:

```
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    isLoggedIn: boolean

    // reference to the isLoggedIn$ subscription, see ngOnDestroy
    private _sub: Subscription

    constructor(private ss: SharedService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._sub = this.ss.isLoggedIn$.subscribe(loginState => isLoggedIn = loginState)
    }

    // Unsubscribe from login state on destroy to prevent memory leak
    ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this._sub.unsubscribe()
    }
}
```